D3D11on12 cant query IDXGISurface from the (wrapped) ID3D11Resource when not wrapping backbuffer
In the sample code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/d2d-using-d3d11on12 for using D2D with D3D11on12 you compose these three functions together
ID3D11On12Device::CreateWrappedResource
ID3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface<IDXGISurface>
ID2D1DeviceContext::CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface

However, when I'm wrapping a swapchain buffer the QueryInterface works. When I am wrapping just a normal ID3D12Resource I get 0x80004002 : 'No such interface supported'.
From the sample code
ThrowIfFailed(m_d3d11On12Device->CreateWrappedResource(
            m_renderTargets[n].Get(),
            &d3d11Flags,
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET,
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_wrappedBackBuffers[n])
            ));

        // Create a render target for D2D to draw directly to this back buffer.
        ComPtr<IDXGISurface> surface;
        ThrowIfFailed(m_wrappedBackBuffers[n].As(&surface));
        ThrowIfFailed(m_d2dDeviceContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(
            surface.Get(),
            &bitmapProperties,
            &m_d2dRenderTargets[n]
            ));

My code
winrt::com_ptr<ID2D1Bitmap1> d2dBitmap;
winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Resource> d3d11Resource;

auto desc = d3dx12::CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(
    DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, text_metrics.width, 53);
desc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET;

winrt::com_ptr<ID3D12Resource> d3d12Resource;
auto heapProperties = d3dx12::CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
winrt::check_hresult(resources.D3D12Device().CreateCommittedResource(
    &heapProperties,
    D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
    &desc,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
    nullptr,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(d3d12Resource.put())));

D3D11_RESOURCE_FLAGS d3d11Flags = { D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET };
winrt::check_hresult(
m_d3d11On12Device->CreateWrappedResource(
    d3d12Resource.get(),
    &d3d11Flags,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(d3d11Resource.put())
));

auto tex2d = d3d11Resource.as<ID3D11Texture2D>(); // good!
auto surface2 = tex2d.as<IDXGISurface>(); //0x80004002 : 'No such interface supported'.
auto surface = d3d11Resource.as<IDXGISurface>(); //0x80004002 : 'No such interface supported'.


CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D doesn't default the number mips levels to 1
Setting to 1 fixes the problem.
auto desc = d3dx12::CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Tex2D(
    DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, text_metrics.width, 53,
    1U, 1U, 1U, 0U,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET
);

